# Understanding and breaking down these sentences

Tags: verbs, subjects

Can someone help me grammatically analyze (what is the object,subject,verb etc.) the following two sentences

> - Suddenly she realized that the brakes weren't working.
> - Unfortunately, since his wife's death his teenage daughter had become extremely difficult.

I know *Suddenly* and *Unfortunately* are adverbs of time and opinion, but the rest I am having difficulty with.

Comment: ***Suddenly*** is just an "ordinary" adverb in your first example - it modifies the verb ***realized***, which it could just as well have been placed immediately before or after. In the second example, ***unfortunately*** is a "sentence adverb" (it modifies the entirety of the rest of the utterance).

Comment: ...It might help to imagine how the meanings would change if you swapped those two adverb between the example sentences; the same "verb / sentence" scope distinction would still apply in exactly the same way. *Unfortunately she realized that the brakes weren't working* implies the writer didn't want her to notice the brake failure, for some reason. And *Suddenly since his wife's death his teenage daughter had become extremely difficult.* is awkward phrasing, but the meaning would be that the daughter ***suddenly became*** difficult.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks - but I was more curious as to what the subject of these two sentences are, what the object is and what the verbs are.....

Comment: 1: ***She** realized something*, 2: ***his daughter** became something*. The primary ***verbs*** immediately follow those highlighted ***subjects***, but I'm not sure how useful it is to look for "objects" in these examples. There might be things like "dependent clauses" involved here, but I have little interest in this kind of "naming of the parts" (which is why I'm only *commenting*, not posting an actual *Answer*).

Comment: ...my only interest here is in pointing out the difference in "scope" for "sentence adverbs" as opposed to the more common examples where an adverb clearly modifies a specific *verb* in an utterance.